# How to extract the text 5000 from the table using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

Need to get the XPATH of following element in the table:
Here the value 5000 is varying but Unit Voltage is constant text, need to get an xpath with following element concept, had tried below xpath, but its not working :

```
//div[contains(text(),'')]/follows/div/span[contains(text(),'Unit voltage (V)')]
```

The Concerns are there ID changes for each environment so cant be used, need help in getting working xpath on above format.

PFB the HTML code part

```html
<tr class="v-formlayout-row v-formlayout-firstrow">
  <td class="v-formlayout-captioncell">
    <div class="v-caption v-caption-tiny v-caption-smalllabel v-caption-hasdescription">
      <span id="gwt-uid-207" for="gwt-uid-208">Unit voltage (V)</span>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="v-formlayout-errorcell">
    <div class="v-formlayout-error-indicator">
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="v-formlayout-contentcell">
    <div class="v-label v-widget tiny v-label-tiny smalllabel v-label-smalllabel v-label-undef-w" id="gwt-uid-208" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-207" style="">5000&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: what you want xpath for `5000` or xpath for lable `Unit voltage (V)` ?

Comment: I assumed you required xpath for extracting the value 5000 which is varying, suggested xpaths in my below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below given xpaths for getting the value 5000.

```
Option 1:
//tr//child::td[contains(@class,'contentcell')]//child::div[contains(@id,'gwt-uid')]

Option 2:
//td[contains(@class,'contentcell')]//child::div[contains(@id,'gwt-uid')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
//span[contains(text(),'Unit voltage')]//ancestor::td//following::td[contains(@class,'contentcell')]//div
```

Or

```
//*[text()='Unit voltage']//following::td[contains(@class,'contentcell')]//div
```

Both should work.

These will return you div element, use `getText()` method to extract the text.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text **5000** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- *xpath 1*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Unit voltage (V)']//following::td[2]/div"))).getText());
  ```
- *xpath 2*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(., 'Unit voltage (V)')]//following::td[2]/div"))).getText());
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks all for your valuable inputs, Below xpath worked for me, as there were multiple elements and the element order is same across environments used as below:

```
(//tr//child::td[contains(@class,'contentcell')]//child::div[contains(@id,'gwt-uid')])[7]
```